# single quotes(') Insert problem in sql server 2005 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, escaping

```
txtname.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "' + char(39) + '")
```

the above statement is not working for stored procedure

Comment: What database are you using? Which programming language? It looks like VB, but you should specify it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't build the sql manually. Use Parameters instead.

Comment: if i build sql manually it's working fine bbut if i use parameters it will not work

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Doing it manually is guaranteed to make your code vurnerable for sql injection attacks and will cause problems with special characters like quotes and special data like dates. 
Tell us more about your enviroment and your code. Then we can give you more precise suggestions on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do? If you want to make the string "safe" for embedding in an SQL query, you might want this instead:

```
txtname.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")
```

...but I would strongly encourage you to use a parameter instead, if possible. Then you don't need to bother about the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution [here](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_escape_single_quotes_in_SQL_queries%3f). Theres a guide how to use the Parameters or how to escape the single quote by hand.

Hope this helps..